# Black screen on iPad storyboard using splitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, storyboard

I have an app whose iPhone storyboard is working fine. My iPad storyboard (which uses a split view controller) just comes up with a black screen.

- Logging tells me that both the master and detail view controllers' `-viewDidLoad:` methods are being called
- Logging also tells me that my detail's view's `-drawRect:` is being called

I didn't post code because I think the problem lies in my storyboard setup (iPhone storyboard works fine).

**Update**: `-viewDidAppear:` *isn't* being called in either of my view controllers, either.

Answer (score 1):

On an iPhone application, you can specify the root view of your application with the **"Main nib file base name"** key in the info.plist file.  From the sound of it, the correct root view is not getting loaded for the iPad.  Trying adding/or setting the correct view for **"Main nib file base name (iPad)"** in your info.plist file.

Also, make sure you are using the correct application lifecycle method to load your views.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {

        [self.window addSubview:yourSplitViewController.view];

    } else {

        [self.window addSubview:yourNavigationController.view];

    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm using XCode 4, my info.plist file has an entry `Main storyboard file base name (iPad)` which is set to `iPad`. That appears to be working ok.  


About the `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method: I can check against `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`, but I don't know how to reference my split view controller object here. In any case, I have other demo projects which use a split view controller on the iPad and only return YES in this method they don't do anything else, which leads me to think that the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Are you using a nib for the iPad root view controller or laying everything out in code?

Comment: Thanks for your help @jerry, I've figured it out after quite some time. It turns out my view is calling a dataSource that isn't set up yet. Why this makes the whole screen black I don't know, but at least I'm on the right path now.